# Not getting data for authenticated user from database in Laravel for setting stripe

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I've been trying to get the saved customer id for stripe from database but with no luck.
It works everywhere else, I could get it and save it again if I wanted, but whenever I try to use it in payment intent to automatically renew a subscription, it gives me this error: `Trying to get property 'stripecustomerid' of non-object`.

this is the bit of the stripe code for recurring charge where the error happens:

```
 public function renew($subscription)
    {
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_XXXXXXXX');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');


        try {
               $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
               $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
               $user = \Auth::user();

               $payment_methods = \Stripe\PaymentMethod::all([
                    'customer' => $user->stripecustomerid,
                    'type' => 'card'
                ]);

               $payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                    'amount' => $subscription->plan->stripePrice(),
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'customer' => $user->stripecustomerid,
                    'payment_method' => $payment_methods->data[0]->id,
                    'off_session' => true,
                    'confirm' => true,

                ]);

               echo json_encode([
                    'paymentIntent' => $payment_intent,
                ]);
           }
      catch (\Exception $e) {
                http_response_code(500);
                echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
      }

    }
```

and `stripecustomerid` is the name of the column where I saved the customer id.

I can print it in another function, and it works when I use GET, but it just doesn't work when the subscription tries to renew.

Comment: try dd($user->toArray());

Comment: Your variable is empty. First check variable

Comment: @A.ANoman I'm sure it's not empty, it even works when I use GET so it's not empty I believe.

Comment: you may try like this format `$user['stripecustomerid']`

Comment: @A.ANoman now another error `Missing required param: customer.` 
I'm just gonna change the entire code that checks the expired subscription and see if the error is caused by something else

Comment: Auth::User() doesn't get the user from the database, it gets the current logged-in user. If no one is logged in Auth::user will be null and then $user will be null.